# Facebook php - How can I detect people like my page

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

For example, I have http://www.example.com/abc.html.

If I like this page, how can I detect me that have already like this page using facebook php api.

Give me help, please

Comment: Wouldn't that be an invasion of your users' privacy? And hen you can discriminate what you show them based on that... seems shady to me.

Comment: from what I've seen of the Facebook API, it only works on Facebook URLs.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832018/detect-like-with-facebook-javascript-api-iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page

Comment: @EtiennePerot how's that invasion of privacy? Is it also invasion of privacy when your wine seller decides to cut you a deal for "liking" his shop?

Comment: @Jack No, but I do think that it is an invasion of privacy for the wine seller to be able to know whether you like his shop or not without asking you.

Comment: @EtiennePerot but when I like a page, I'm already telling you that I like the page (i.e. `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', ... `)

Comment: @Jack I see. I suppose the analogy doesn't really hold when using the facebook meaning of the word "like". As you can tell, I am not really familiar with these things, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can collect who likes your page using the newest facebook sdk. What you would do is a sort of work around using their app interface, which is just a LIKE script for your site, and then call https://graph.facebook.com//subscriptions to record the information via mysql or whatever db you are using. I use this method when collecting facebook invites for random contests I hold.

Comment: Thanks all guy reply. I am green of facebook api

Someone can give me some code for explanation.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies that must be set in the Like button callback or can use Facebook Connect to check whether a user likes your page but this way requires extra permissions and a created facebook app.

Also there is a ready solution for jquery:
http://codecanyon.net/item/like-2-unlock-for-jquery/2822035